поиск маркеров в режиме реального времени через web-камеру
Мне нужно найти маркер на изображении с помощью веб-камеры в режиме реального времени. Как это можно сделать на C#? у меня есть web-камера от ps3 и мишень. Нужно что бы камера могла распознать мишень и найти центр. У меня есть код он вроде бы находит маркер, но он ищет не так как надо. Помогите хотя бы словесным алгоритмом

using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace Shooting
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private FilterInfoCollection CaptureDevices;
        private VideoCaptureDevice FinalFrame;
        private bool searchPixels = false;
        private Rectangle? foundMarker = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            foreach (FilterInfo Device in CaptureDevices)
            {
                DeviceNameToolStripMenuItem.Items.Add(Device.Name);
            }
            DeviceNameToolStripMenuItem.SelectedIndex = 0;
            StartVideoImage();
        }

        private void StartVideoImage()
        {
            FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice(CaptureDevices[DeviceNameToolStripMenuItem.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
            FinalFrame.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalFrame_NewFrame);
            FinalFrame.Start();
        }

        private void FinalFrame_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            /* Bitmap image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
             Bitmap grayscaleImage = MakeGrayscale((Bitmap)image);
             Bitmap binaryImage = Binarize(grayscaleImage, CalculateBlackThreshold(grayscaleImage));
             ProcessImage(binaryImage);*/

            System.Drawing.Image image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

            image = MakeGrayscale((Bitmap)image);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
            {
                int width = image.Width;
                int height = image.Height;


                int thirdWidth = width / 3;
                int thirdHeight = height / 3;

                g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, thirdWidth, 0, thirdWidth, height);
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 2 * thirdWidth, 0, 2 * thirdWidth, height);
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 0, thirdHeight, width, thirdHeight);
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 0, 2 * thirdHeight, width, 2 * thirdHeight);
                int centerX = width / 2;
                int centerY = height / 2;
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, centerX - 10, centerY, centerX + 10, centerY);

                g.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, centerX, centerY - 10, centerX, centerY + 10);
            }

            if (searchPixels)
            {
                ProcessImage((Bitmap)image);
            }

            VideoImage.Image = image;
        }


        private void ProcessImage(Bitmap image)
        {
            Bitmap binaryImage = Binarize(image, CalculateBlackThreshold(image));

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
            {
                Rectangle? markerRect = FindMarker(binaryImage);

                if (markerRect.HasValue)
                {

                    if (IsSurroundedByWhite(binaryImage, markerRect.Value))
                    {

                        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Yellow, markerRect.Value);
                    }
                    /*else
                    {

                        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, markerRect.Value);
                    }*/
                }
            }
        }


        private Rectangle? FindMarker(Bitmap binaryImage)
        {
            int width = binaryImage.Width;
            int height = binaryImage.Height;

            // Определение границ первого квадранта
            int firstQuadrantStartX = 0;
            int firstQuadrantStartY = 0;
            int firstQuadrantEndX = width / 3;
            int firstQuadrantEndY = height / 3;

            // Определение границ девятого квадранта
            int ninthQuadrantStartX = 2 * (width / 3);
            int ninthQuadrantStartY = 2 * (height / 3);
            int ninthQuadrantEndX = width;
            int ninthQuadrantEndY = height;

            int maxDistance = 3;

            // Поиск маркера в девятом квадранте
            Rectangle? foundMarker = SearchInQuadrant(binaryImage, ninthQuadrantStartX, ninthQuadrantStartY, ninthQuadrantEndX, ninthQuadrantEndY, maxDistance);
            if (foundMarker.HasValue)
            {
                return foundMarker;
            }

            // Поиск маркера в первом квадранте
            foundMarker = SearchInQuadrant(binaryImage, firstQuadrantStartX, firstQuadrantStartY, firstQuadrantEndX, firstQuadrantEndY, maxDistance);
            if (foundMarker.HasValue)
            {
                return foundMarker;
            }

            return null;
        }


        private Rectangle? SearchInQuadrant(Bitmap binaryImage, int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY, int maxDistance)
        {
            int? minX = null, minY = null, maxX = null, maxY = null;

            // Поиск последовательностей черных и белых пикселей по строкам
            for (int y = startY; y < endY; y++)
            {
                int currentColor = -1; // -1 означает, что цвет еще не определен
                int count = 0; // Счетчик последовательности
                int lastX = -1;

                for (int x = startX; x < endX; x++)
                {
                    int pixelColor = binaryImage.GetPixel(x, y).R;

                    if (pixelColor != currentColor)
                    {
                        if (currentColor != -1)
                        {
                            // Проверка на черный и белый пиксели
                            if ((currentColor == 0 && pixelColor == 255) || (currentColor == 255 && pixelColor == 0))
                            {
                                count++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                count = 1; // Сброс счетчика
                            }
                        }

                        currentColor = pixelColor;
                        lastX = x;

                        // Если нашли последовательность, сохраняем координаты
                        if (count >= 2) // Измените это значение, если нужно
                        {
                            if (!minX.HasValue || x < minX) minX = x;
                            if (!maxX.HasValue || x > maxX) maxX = x;
                            if (!minY.HasValue || y < minY) minY = y;
                            if (!maxY.HasValue || y > maxY) maxY = y;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Поиск последовательностей черных и белых пикселей по столбцам
            for (int x = startX; x < endX; x++)
            {
                int currentColor = -1;
                int count = 0;
                int lastY = -1;

                for (int y = startY; y < endY; y++)
                {
                    int pixelColor = binaryImage.GetPixel(x, y).R;

                    if (pixelColor != currentColor)
                    {
                        if (currentColor != -1)
                        {
                            // Проверка на черный и белый пиксели
                            if ((currentColor == 0 && pixelColor == 255) || (currentColor == 255 && pixelColor == 0))
                            {
                                count++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                count = 1; // Сброс счетчика
                            }
                        }

                        currentColor = pixelColor;
                        lastY = y;

                        // Если нашли последовательность, сохраняем координаты
                        if (count >= 2) // Измените это значение, если нужно
                        {
                            if (!minX.HasValue || x < minX) minX = x;
                            if (!maxX.HasValue || x > maxX) maxX = x;
                            if (!minY.HasValue || y < minY) minY = y;
                            if (!maxY.HasValue || y > maxY) maxY = y;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Проверка на наличие найденного маркера
            if (minX.HasValue && minY.HasValue && maxX.HasValue && maxY.HasValue)
            {
                return new Rectangle(minX.Value, minY.Value, maxX.Value - minX.Value, maxY.Value - minY.Value);
            }

            return null;
        }


        private Bitmap Binarize(Bitmap original, int threshold)
        {
            Bitmap binarizedBmp = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height);
            BitmapData originalData = original.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, original.PixelFormat);
            BitmapData binarizedData = binarizedBmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, binarizedBmp.PixelFormat);

            unsafe
            {
                byte* originalPtr = (byte*)originalData.Scan0;
                byte* binarizedPtr = (byte*)binarizedData.Scan0;

                for (int y = 0; y < original.Height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < original.Width; x++)
                    {
                        int pixelIndex = y * originalData.Stride + x * 4;
                        byte blue = originalPtr[pixelIndex];
                        byte green = originalPtr[pixelIndex + 1];
                        byte red = originalPtr[pixelIndex + 2];

                        int brightness = (int)(red * 0.3 + green * 0.59 + blue * 0.11);
                        byte newColor = (byte)(brightness >= threshold ? 255 : 0);

                        binarizedPtr[pixelIndex] = newColor;
                        binarizedPtr[pixelIndex + 1] = newColor;
                        binarizedPtr[pixelIndex + 2] = newColor;
                        binarizedPtr[pixelIndex + 3] = 255;
                    }
                }
            }

            original.UnlockBits(originalData);
            binarizedBmp.UnlockBits(binarizedData);
            return binarizedBmp;
        }

        private int CalculateBlackThreshold(Bitmap image)
        {
            double averageBrightness = CalculateAverageBrightness(image);
            double standardDeviation = CalculateStandardDeviation(image, averageBrightness);
            return (int)(averageBrightness - 2 * standardDeviation);
        }
        private double CalculateAverageBrightness(Bitmap image)
        {
            int sumBrightness = 0;
            int count = 0;

            for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
                {
                    Color pixelColor = image.GetPixel(x, y);
                    int brightness = (int)(pixelColor.R * 0.3 + pixelColor.G * 0.59 + pixelColor.B * 0.11);
                    sumBrightness += brightness;
                    count++;
                }
            }

            return (double)sumBrightness / count;
        }

        private double CalculateStandardDeviation(Bitmap image, double averageBrightness)
        {
            double sumSquaredDifference = 0;
            int count = 0;

            for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
                {
                    Color pixelColor = image.GetPixel(x, y);
                    int brightness = (int)(pixelColor.R * 0.3 + pixelColor.G * 0.59 + pixelColor.B * 0.11);
                    double squaredDifference = Math.Pow(brightness - averageBrightness, 2);
                    sumSquaredDifference += squaredDifference;
                    count++;
                }
            }

            return Math.Sqrt(sumSquaredDifference / count);
        }

        public Bitmap MakeGrayscale(Bitmap original)
        {
            Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newBmp))
            {
                ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]
                {
                        new float[] {0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 0, 0},
                        new float[] {0.59f, 0.59f, 0.59f, 0, 0},
                        new float[] {0.11f, 0.11f, 0.11f, 0, 0},
                        new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                        new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
                });

                ImageAttributes imgAttr = new ImageAttributes();
                imgAttr.SetColorMatrix(colorMatrix);
                g.DrawImage(original, new Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height),
                    0, 0, original.Width, original.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgAttr);
            }

            return newBmp;
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (FinalFrame != null)
            {
                if (FinalFrame.IsRunning)
                {
                    FinalFrame.SignalToStop();
                    FinalFrame.WaitForStop();
                }
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            searchPixels = true;
        }

        private void BlackThresholdTrackBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private bool IsSurroundedByWhite(Bitmap binaryImage, Rectangle marker)
        {
            bool isInFirstQuadrant = marker.Left < binaryImage.Width / 3 && marker.Top < binaryImage.Height / 3;
            bool isInNinthQuadrant = marker.Left >= 2 * (binaryImage.Width / 3) && marker.Top >= 2 * (binaryImage.Height / 3);

            if (isInFirstQuadrant)
            {
                // Проверка для первого квадранта
                for (int x = marker.Left; x <= marker.Right; x++)
                {
                    if (x < 0 || x >= binaryImage.Width) continue;
                    if (binaryImage.GetPixel(x, marker.Bottom + 1).R == 0) return false; // Проверка снизу
                }

                for (int y = marker.Top; y <= marker.Bottom; y++)
                {
                    if (marker.Right + 1 >= binaryImage.Width) return false;
                    if (binaryImage.GetPixel(marker.Right + 1, y).R == 0) return false; // Проверка справа
                }
            }
            else if (isInNinthQuadrant)
            {
                // Проверка для девятого квадранта
                if (marker.Top > 0)
                {
                    for (int x = marker.Left - 1; x <= marker.Right + 1; x++)
                    {
                        if (x < 0 || x >= binaryImage.Width) continue;
                        if (binaryImage.GetPixel(x, marker.Top - 1).R == 0) return false; // Проверка сверху
                    }
                }

                if (marker.Bottom + 1 < binaryImage.Height)
                {
                    for (int x = marker.Left - 1; x <= marker.Right + 1; x++)
                    {
                        if (x < 0 || x >= binaryImage.Width) continue;
                        if (binaryImage.GetPixel(x, marker.Bottom + 1).R == 0) return false; // Проверка снизу
                    }
                }

                if (marker.Left > 0)
                {
                    for (int y = marker.Top; y <= marker.Bottom; y++)
                    {
                        if (marker.Left - 1 < 0) return false;
                        if (binaryImage.GetPixel(marker.Left - 1, y).R == 0) return false; // Проверка слева
                    }
                }

                if (marker.Right + 1 < binaryImage.Width)
                {
                    for (int y = marker.Top; y <= marker.Bottom; y++)
                    {
                        if (marker.Right + 1 >= binaryImage.Width) return false;
                        if (binaryImage.GetPixel(marker.Right + 1, y).R == 0) return false; // Проверка справа
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Проверка для других квадрантов (если необходимо)
                if (marker.Top > 0)
                {
                    for (int x = marker.Left - 1; x <= marker.Right + 1; x++)
                    {
                        if (x < 0 || x >= binaryImage.Width) continue;
                        if (binaryImage.GetPixel(x, marker.Top - 1).R == 0) return false; // Проверка сверху
                    }
                }

                if (marker.Bottom + 1 < binaryImage.Height)
                {
                    for (int x = marker.Left - 1; x <= marker.Right + 1; x++)
                    {
                        if (x < 0 || x >= binaryImage.Width) continue;
                        if (binaryImage.GetPixel(x, marker.Bottom + 1).R == 0) return false; // Проверка снизу
                    }
                }

                if (marker.Left > 0)
                {
                    for (int y = marker.Top; y <= marker.Bottom; y++)
                    {
                        if (marker.Left - 1 < 0) return false;
                        if (binaryImage.GetPixel(marker.Left - 1, y).R == 0) return false; // Проверка слева
                    }
                }

                if (marker.Right + 1 < binaryImage.Width)
                {
                    for (int y = marker.Top; y <= marker.Bottom; y++)
                    {
                        if (marker.Right + 1 >= binaryImage.Width) return false;
                        if (binaryImage.GetPixel(marker.Right + 1, y).R == 0) return false; // Проверка справа
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }


    }
}


как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Вы думаете, что кто-то будет запускать ваших 100500 строк кода? Опишите, пожалуйста, конкретный вопрос или проблему. На каком этапе у вас получается "не так как надо"?

Для поиска объектов на изображении, как правило, используются нейросети. Сам не приходилось реализовывать такое, но такое возможно. Описывать алгоритм поиска вам здесь никто не будет, т.к. материала много. Вам остается лишь изучить его. Рекомендую гуглить следующее "алгоритмы распознавания образов"

Попробуй погуглить про библиотеку OpenCV, это библиотека компьютерного зрения
